# How do I know that the Instagram button has been selected?

Tags: ios, react-native

How do I know when the application has been clicked? I'm using 'Share' from React Native. I want to know as **soon as** a user clicks an app icon (e.g. Instagram) and then launch my own function, not the share page in Instagram. How can I capture that the user has just clicked the app icon?

Right now if I click the app icon, it moves to the app's (e.g. Instagram's) share page, and when I dismiss it, then it tells me what my `sharedAction` was (which is too late!). I don't want to have to enter the share page at all.

I need to know **when** I've selected the Instagram app icon, so I can launch my own function.

```
import { Share } from 'react-native' 

shareImage = async() => {

    const result = await Share.share(

      {
        message: 'Hello',
        url: "www.image...."
      },
    )
    .then(res => console.log(res))


    if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
      if (result.activityType) {
        // shared with activity type of result.activityType
      } else {
        // shared
      }
    } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
      // dismissed
    }
}
```

[image: See image here]

Answer (score 0):

In general you can get information from `result.activityType`. Unfortunately I don't know the activityType of Instagram, but you can try it out by checking the activityType. Below, I have an example where we want to detect if the Clipboard was used.

**For example:**

```
if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
      console.log(result.activityType) // here you can see the activityType
      if (result.activityType == "com.apple.UIKit.activity.CopyToPasteboard") {
        // Copy to Clipboard was used 
      }
      // first you have to check the activityType of instagram 
      if (result.activityType == "INSTAGRAM_ACITVITY_TYPE") {
        // Instagram share extension was used
      } 
    } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
      // dismissed
}
```

Comment: The activity type is 'com.burbn.instagram.shareextension'. However that is only returned AFTER clicking the button & it automatically takes you to a page to share your link. When you cancel out of that share page, THEN the activityType gets filled. What i was after was to not enter that share page, and just know that the Instagram button had been clicked.

Comment: @chai86 that's not possible to do